# Programmatically Restore a Microsoft SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, database-backups, database-restore

I wish to use ColdFusion to grab a database backup from a live server and restore it into a test environment. The grabbing bit is done, but I can't find a way of restoring the database programatically forcibly overwriting the database if its already there.

Any help would be appreicated, I figured there should be some SQL script or batch file that could do the job for me.

Obviously windows environment. SQL 2008, ColdFusion 9.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I generally prefer using SSIS to do this sort of tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
----Put database into single user mode (terminates open connections - else restore fails)
ALTER DATABASE YourDB
SET SINGLE_USER WITH
ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE


RESTORE DATABASE YourDB 
FROM DISK = 'D:\temp\YourDB.bak' 
WITH REPLACE 
,MOVE 'YourDB_Data' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\YourDB_Data.mdf'
,MOVE 'YourDB_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\YourDB_Data.ldf'


ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET MULTI_USER
GO
```